# How to split one section of string via Tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I try to split this string `3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM` and get this string  `1395/9/3` .I search but sql has no method for this work. How to do this?

Comment: I suppose your DBMS is Sql Server, right?

Comment: Different databases will deal with this differently. Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle for example? Once we know the system you're using it will help you get better answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your variable to a Date and get Year, Month and Day

```
DATEPART(YEAR,Cast('3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM' as date)) 

DATEPART(MONTH,Cast('3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM' as date)) 

DATEPART(DAY,Cast('3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM' as date))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is a really hacky way of doing this and would work for values that aren't dates that you need to split. There's easier ways of answering this particular question as it's to do with dates but for general string splitting you can take this approach;

Test Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (OriginalString varchar(22))
INSERT INTO #TestData (OriginalString)
VALUES
('3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM')
,('10/9/1462 04:00:00 AM')
,('25/12/1900 15:00:00 PM')
,('3/11/1264 13:00:00 PM')
```

Result Query;

```
SELECT
OriginalString
,RIGHT(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX(' ',OriginalString,1)-1),4) + '/' + RIGHT(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1)-1),LEN(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1)-1))-CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)) + '/' + LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)-1) Result
FROM #TestData
```

Which gives these results;

```
OriginalString          Result
3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM    1395/9/3
10/9/1462 04:00:00 AM   1462/9/10
25/12/1900 15:00:00 PM  1900/12/25
3/11/1264 13:00:00 PM   1264/11/3
```

To get to this result, I built the result part by part and worked from there, if you take a look at the following query you can see how I came to this answer, it may help you if you need to do this again in future;

```
SELECT
OriginalString
,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1) FirstSlashLocation
,LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)-1) FirstValue
,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1) SecondSlashLocation
,RIGHT(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1)-1),LEN(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1)-1))-CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)) SecondValue
,CHARINDEX(' ',OriginalString,1) SpaceLocation
,RIGHT(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX(' ',OriginalString,1)-1),4) FinalValue
,RIGHT(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX(' ',OriginalString,1)-1),4) + '/' + RIGHT(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1)-1),LEN(LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)+1)-1))-CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)) + '/' + LEFT(OriginalString,CHARINDEX('/',OriginalString,1)-1) Result
FROM #TestData
```

Which gives these results;

```
OriginalString          FirstSlashLocation  FirstValue  SecondSlashLocation SecondValue SpaceLocation   FinalValue  Result
3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM    2                   3           4                   9           9               1395        1395/9/3
10/9/1462 04:00:00 AM   3                   10          5                   9           10              1462        1462/9/10
25/12/1900 15:00:00 PM  3                   25          6                   12          11              1900        1900/12/25
3/11/1264 13:00:00 PM   2                   3           5                   11          10              1264        1264/11/3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you column is date  you could use

```
select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),your_column , 110) from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DBMS is Sql Server (I suppose becuase in your title you've written Tsql)

Try this:

```
select 
    substring('3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM', 0, 
    charindex(' ', '3/9/1395 12:00:00 AM')
)
```

Your pattern is always date space time, so you'll get the first space position (with `charindex` function) and the you apply a `substring` function on your string

Comment: This return 3/9/1395 but I want get 1395/9/3